# split a string using regular expression in perl

Tags: regex, perl, split

I have a string which is of this form:

> $str = "30M1I20M150N20M190N50M"

EDITED: I would like to split this string so that my ouput looks like this:

> 30M1I20M
>   150N
>   20M
>   190N
>   50M

However, when I tried with,

> @split_str = split(/(\d+)N/, $str);

I get:

> 30M1I20M
>   150
>   20M
>   190
>   50M

As you can see, the N gets omitted in the result (150, 190 instead of 150N and 190N). Could anyone tell me how I should go about? Thank you!

Comment: Your example does not make sense: if you split on N keeping the N you get: 30M1I20M150N, 20M190N and 50M. Did I get something wrong?

Comment: You can as suggested in the answers put the N in the capture group or just reattach it to the strings

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put the N *inside* the capture group.

```
/(\d+N)/
```

Answer (score 1):

try the following (not tested):

```
split(/(\d+?[MN])/, $str);
```

Comment: Since I guess you are trying to get also 'M's

Answer (score 1):

See [*Look-around assertions* in `perlre`](http://p3rl.org/perlre#Look-Around-Assertions).

```
split /(?<=[NM])/, '30M1I20M150N20M190N50M'
# returns
# qw(
#     30M
#     1I20M
#     150N
#     20M
#     190N
#     50M
# )
```

Comment: I believe the '?<=' is a look ahead insertion? I never really understood those, what exactly it does? thanks

Comment: See [*Look-around assertions* in `perlre`](http://p3rl.org/perlre#Look-Around-Assertions). But I'm repeating myself.